# Qt Object Wrapper Around Network API

Tags: c++, qt

I am working on developing an API of Qt objects that abstracts communication with a piece of hardware.  This hardware has a TCP-based API for interfacing with it.  The hardware has a few properties (e.g. device name, ip address, etc...), control function (e.g. turn on or off a logic output), and events it can produce (e.g. a logic value has changed).

When creating my objects I have naturally made the properties of the device into object properties (i.e. private variables with getters and setters).  The control functions are implemented in the objects as public functions/slots which implement the appropriate underlying TCP query.  The events are received by the socket, processed, and emitted by my objects as signals.

All of this works well except there are a few complications I can't seem to work out a good way to solve.  Firstly, the Qt sockets interface is naturally all event-based making some semantics of my object API difficult.  For example, if i want to get the name of my object I would do the following:

```
QString name = MyObject->name();
```

However the problem is this information comes from a query to the TCP socket.  Since everything is supposed to be non-blocking, how would I be able to fetch a property in this manner.  Additionally, the device may produce an event which indicates a change in a property which this object needs to receive and change its internal properties accordingly (not that difficult though).

The only idea I can come up with is having some sort of *ready()* function which the user can call to check if the data in the object has been fetched from the API.

Perhaps a concrete example will help (there may be minor syntax errors):

```
class Device: public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
private:
    QString property1_;
    QString property2_;

    NetworkApi *api_;
public:
    void Device(NetworkApi *api, QObject *parent = 0);

    QString property1();
    QString property2();
signals:
    void eventOccurred(QString arg); //An event from the api is parsed and then this signal is emitted
public slots:
    QString setProperty1(QString val); //Performs a network query
    QString setProperty2(QString val); //Performs a network query

    QString performAction(); //Causes the device to perform some action by making a network query
};
```

In my API each API object stores a pointer to an object which handles all the socket things.  If you were to call the performAction() this object would tell the API to make a query to the physical device.  This device would then eventually raise an event that says an action has been performed (e.g. "turn on the output" -> "the output has been turned on").  This object receives the event from the API object, parses it, and produces a signal.

Hopefully what I am trying to accomplish makes sense.  Let me know if I need to provide further information.

Thanks,
Patrick

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Do you have control over the device? Is it plain TCP, or some higher level protocol like HTTP the device provides?

Comment: Qt already provides classes for non-blocking access to [TCP sockets](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcpsocket.html) and advanced [network functionalities](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-index.html). Did you already look at them? If yes, why didn't it do for you? I've got the impression you try to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: The device is just using its own TCP protocol. Also, I am using the Qt TCP sockets with non-blocking functionality. I guess what I am asking is what would be the best way to indicate to the user information about these objects in a non-blocking manner without having a race condition. For instance, maybe the object will initiate a TCP query when it is constructed to fetch the initial information about the device. If the user wants this information right afterwards, it probably hasn't been received by the TCP socket yet and the object will have to return some Null (or equivalent) values.